# Is there a way to use the GroundProjectedSkybox object from three.js in an AFrame project?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I came across a method to create a ground-projected environment in three.js, and I want to use this in my AFrame project. I'm aware that AFrame is built on three.js, so I assume that I should be able to utilize the three.js API to achieve this. However, I'm not sure how to incorporate the GroundProjectedSkybox object from three.js into my AFrame project.

For reference, here is an example of the ground-projected environment in three.js along with the relevant code:

[See example here](https://raw.githack.com/FarazzShaikh/three.js/feat/envmaps-ground-projected/examples/index.html?q=ground#webgl_materials_envmaps_ground-projected)

[Relevant code in three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/objects/GroundProjectedSkybox.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the relevant classes from threejs, or use [my `ground-projected-skybox` component](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/tree/master/aframe/three-components):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/three-components/dist/ground-projected-skybox.js"></script>

<a-scene  ground-projected-skybox="envMapUrl: https://threejs.org/examples/textures/equirectangular/blouberg_sunrise_2_1k.hdr"
          renderer="colorManagement: true;">
    <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow material="metalness: 1; roughness: 0"></a-box>
    <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow material="metalness: 1; roughness: 0"></a-sphere>
    <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow material="metalness: 1; roughness: 0"></a-cylinder>
    <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow="receive: true"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

all it needs is a `envMapUrl` to the hdr texture (which in the above example is from [threejs.org](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/textures/equirectangular/blouberg_sunrise_2_1k.hdr))

Comment: Wow, that's truly remarkable and exceeds all my expectations. I can't thank you enough for your help on this. I'm very grateful, Thank you so much!